# vue.js + vuetify radio buttons do not work when they have the same values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How can I make radio button 1 selectable, even if it has the same value with another radio button?

Example: the user selects which characteristics the value contains the price for the characteristic of something. If I chose 1 and value 20, then the character should not be selected. 2 value 20

```
<script>
        new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data () {

          }
        })
</script>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 md6>
          <v-subheader>Light</v-subheader>
          <v-card flat>
            <v-card-text>
              <p>{{ ex8 || 'null' }}</p>
              <v-radio-group v-model="ex8" :mandatory="false">
                <v-radio label="Radio 1" value="radio-1"></v-radio>
                <v-radio label="Radio 2" value="radio-1"></v-radio>
              </v-radio-group>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 md6>
          <v-subheader>Dark</v-subheader>
          <v-card color="secondary" flat>
            <v-card-text>
              <p class="white--text">{{ ex9 || 'null' }}</p>
              <v-radio-group v-model="ex9" :mandatory="false">
                <v-radio label="Radio 3" value="radio-3" dark></v-radio>
                <v-radio label="Radio 4" value="radio-4" dark></v-radio>
              </v-radio-group>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

P.S.

codepen.io/Pavel8289/pen/dJwzyV ------
Why does not work through the loop? Answers on questions: "I from Ukrain..." >"Travel around America ">any answer> And in the end all items are chosen –

Answer (score 0):

VueJs does optimize the rendering to be small as possible. Add a `:key` to your radio box:

```
<v-radio label="Radio 1" value="radio-1" :key="1"></v-radio>
<v-radio label="Radio 2" value="radio-1" :key="2"></v-radio>
```

Comment: @Pavel8289 the comment section is not the right place to ask to solve your problem

Comment: @C Sharper Don't work, I testing "key" and "name", nothing

Answer (score 0):

" elements of type radio are generally used in radio groups—collections of radio buttons describing a set of related options. Only one radio button in a given group can be selected at the same time. "

Assign the same name to each radio in the group:

```
<v-radio label="Radio 1" value="radio-1" name="price-1"></v-radio>
<v-radio label="Radio 2" value="radio-1" name="price-1"></v-radio>
```

Comment: For example: How much does it cost to print a photo?
color one side of the value (costs )20, two-sided black white photo value (costs) 20.

Comment: Ah ok. Give the radio inputs the same name in this case.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Pavel8289/pen/dJwzyV
please help me, Why does not work through the loop? Answers on questions: "I from Ukrain..." >"Travel around America ">any answer> And in the end all items are chosen